# Android WifiManeger Class startCustomizedScan(ScanSettings requested) function application force stop

Tags: android, wifi, hidden, android-wifi, wifimanager

I must use startCustomizedScan(ScanSettings requested) function. Request a scan for access points in specified channel list. Each channel is specified by its frequency in MHz, e.g. "2437"

```
 WifiChannel mrtChannel;
 mrtChannel = new WifiChannel();

 mrtChannel.freqMHz = 2437;
 mrtChannel.channelNum = 6;

 ScanSettings set ;
 mrtcollection = null;

 mrtcollection.add(mrtChannel);

 set = (ScanSettings)mrtcollection;
 mainWifi.startCustomizedScan(set);
```

but my Application Force Stop. Application do not laucnh. LogCat

```
08-30 23:09:36.547: E/AndroidRuntime(14327): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 23:09:36.547: E/AndroidRuntime(14327): Process: com.muratucan.murat5hidden, PID: 14327
08-30 23:09:36.547: E/AndroidRuntime(14327): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.muratucan.murat5hidden/com.muratucan.murat5hidden.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.Collection.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
08-30 23:09:36.547: E/AndroidRuntime(14327):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
08-30 23:09:36.547: E/AndroidRuntime(14327):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
08-30 23:09:36.547: E/AndroidRuntime(14327):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
08-30 23:09:36.547: E/AndroidRuntime(14327):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
08-30 23:09:36.547: E/AndroidRuntime(14327):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-30 23:09:36.547: E/AndroidRuntime(14327):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-30 23:09:36.547: E/AndroidRuntime(14327):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
08-30 23:09:36.547: E/AndroidRuntime(14327):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-30 23:09:36.547: E/AndroidRuntime(14327):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-30 23:09:36.547: E/AndroidRuntime(14327):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
08-30 23:09:36.547: E/AndroidRuntime(14327):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
08-30 23:09:36.547: E/AndroidRuntime(14327): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.Collection.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
08-30 23:09:36.547: E/AndroidRuntime(14327):    at com.muratucan.murat5hidden.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:133)
08-30 23:09:36.547: E/AndroidRuntime(14327):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
08-30 23:09:36.547: E/AndroidRuntime(14327):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
08-30 23:09:36.547: E/AndroidRuntime(14327):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
```

Please someone give me some insight in this project or other method.

Thanks!

My Full Code is Here..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//  WifiManager mainwifi;

    public  Collection<WifiChannel> channelSetCollect;
    public Collection<WifiChannel> mrtcollection = null;
    TextView ekran ;

    TextView mainText;
    WifiManager mainWifi;
    WifiReceiver receiverWifi;
    List<ScanResult> wifiList;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        // Initiate wifi service manager
        mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

     WifiChannel mrtChannel;
     mrtChannel = new WifiChannel();

     mrtChannel.freqMHz = 2437;
     mrtChannel.channelNum = 6;

     ScanSettings set ;
     mrtcollection = null;

     mrtcollection.add(mrtChannel);

     set = (ScanSettings)mrtcollection;
     mainWifi.startCustomizedScan(set);


        // Check for wifi is disabled
        if (mainWifi.isWifiEnabled() == false)
             {   
                 // If wifi disabled then enable it
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled..making it enabled", 
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 mainWifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
             } 

        // wifi scaned value broadcast receiver 
        receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();

        // Register broadcast receiver 
        // Broacast receiver will automatically call when number of wifi connections changed
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
       // mainWifi.startScan();
        mainText.setText("Starting Scan...");

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiverWifi);
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        super.onResume();
    }

    // Broadcast receiver class called its receive method 
    // when number of wifi connections changed

    class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        // This method call when number of wifi connections changed
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

            sb = new StringBuilder();
            wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults(); 
            sb.append("\n        Number Of Wifi connections :"+wifiList.size()+"\n\n");

            for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++){

                sb.append(new Integer(i+1).toString() + ". ");
                sb.append((wifiList.get(i)).toString());
                sb.append("\n\n");
            }

            mainText.setText(sb);  
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried mCollection = new Collection();?

Comment: Instead of asign it to null it it's a list you can make a clear() if you asign it to null it'll crash cause NullPointerException

Comment: I use   mCollection = new Collection();  code but it'll crash cause NullPointerException

Comment: See my answer below, also it is not possible to simply do "new Collection();" without providing some implementation, since Collection is just an interface.

Comment: 08-31 02:38:58.576: E/AndroidRuntime(23793): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.muratucan.murat5hidden/com.muratucan.murat5hidden.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: LocationHardware: Neither user 10422 nor current process has android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE.

What is the LOCATION_HARDWARE ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a NullPointerException because you are trying to add to a collection, but the collection is null.

```
 mrtcollection = null;

 mrtcollection.add(mrtChannel);
```

What you need to do is initialize the collection:

```
 mrtcollection = new ArrayList<WifiChannel>();
 mrtcollection.add(mrtChannel);
```

Note, you can use any class that implements Collection, not just ArrayList (see [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) to see what classes implement Collection). Also, you can initialize mrtcollection when you define the variable, or you can assign in onCreate.

Update:
For your ClassCastException, you shouldn't be casting an ArrayList to ScanSettings, you should be creating your own ScanSettings using the hidden constructor and setting Collection channelSet with your desired channels.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

I made you say changes but it'll crash cause NullPointerException .. LogCat massege : 08-31 01:12:08.439: E/AndroidRuntime(12011): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.muratucan.murat5hidden/com.muratucan.murat5hidden.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.net.wifi.ScanSettings

Comment: You get a ClassCastException because you are trying to convert ArrayList to ScanSettings: `set = (ScanSettings) mrtcollection;` This is not allowed because ArrayList is not a type of ScanSettings.

Comment: ClassCastException I did not understand how to solve.  how to set ScanSettings  hidden constructor channelSet with channels. how to use channelSet ? Could you please share a simple code example?

Comment: I'll try to post something later, but most likely won't be able to get to it until Wednesday/Thursday. You need to 1) learn how to access the startCustomizedScan method, and 2) learn how to create ScanSettings. These are both hidden, so you should read up on how to use hidden APIs: [Using internal and hidden APIs](https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/). This is actually mentioned on the [Sony Developer Website](http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/tutorials/ui-graphics/code-examples-using-hidden-android-apis/) you are using.

Comment: Did you try to write any more code based on those guides? You have 2 approaches when using hidden APIs: 1) use reflection 2) generate the full Android platform library and compile using it. Once you decide what approach you take you can update your original post with any more problems you face

Comment: Yes I write code but  I have this error in logcat .android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE error what is the meaning 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.muratucan.murat5hidden/com.muratucan.murat5hidden.MainActivity‌​}: java.lang.SecurityException: LocationHardware: Neither user 10422 nor current process has android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE. What is the LOCATION_HARDWARE ?

Comment: Can you update the code as well as posting the stack trace?